# PHP: Including files dependent on each other

Tags: php, file-inclusion

Two files are dependent on each other:

FILE1:

```
$var1 = 'Straw ' . $var2;
```

FILE2:

```
$var2 = ' berry';
$var3 = $var1;
```

FILE3:

```
// this file should include FILE1 and FILE2
```

How should one go about including FILE1 and FILE2 in FILE3 in a way that makes sure the three variables are properly populated?

Thank you.

Comment: That's a circular dependency. That's simply poor design. If two files are that dependent on each other, have them in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Since FILE 1 contains `variable` used in FILE 2, FILE 1 should be `include`d first in FILE 3. So FILE 3 would be something like

```
include ("file1.php");
include ("file2.php");
```

But since the variables are dependent on each other, why not have them in the same file unless you have a reason some how.

**NOTE:** `var2` would be undefined in FILE 1. So my advice is to put both variables that are dependent on each other in one FILE. So FILE 1 an be something like

```
$var2 = ' berry';
$var1 = 'Straw ' . $var2;
```

Then FILE 2

```
$var3 = $var1;
```

Then you `include` as above.

Comment: Both files are using variables from each other, so regardless of what file is included first, one variable will be undefined.

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson didn't notice that.

Comment: Thank you very much @Oke Tega. In this instance, I wouldn't have full control of the order of the variables. If I could however, I would mark your post as the answer.

Comment: @camursm Yea you could.

Answer (score 1):

You actually will get a warning about an undefined variable regardless of the order you include them due to your design — since file 1 requires `$var2` and file 2 requires `$var1`.

Instead do something like this:

```
$var2 = 'berry';
$var1 = 'Straw ' . $var2;
$var3 = $var1;
```

You can split these up in to separate files so long as they are called in the above order.

Comment: Thanks @texalate. This could be one solution. In this example, I wouldn't be able to control the order of the variables however.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks everyone for your input.

One can do as @texelate and @Oke Tega suggests and put the variables in the right order, then distribute them into different files.

But as @Magnus Eriksson pointed out, this is circular dependency and bad design, it simply cannot be done.

Comment: If @texelate's solution solves your issue, then accept that answer instead of writing your own...

Comment: The problem is, I wouldn't be able to control the order of the variables, hence this post.

Comment: Glad we could help but this is not an answer to your question and shouldn't have been posted as an answer. You could comment this. Accept one answer if it helps instead.

Comment: If you can't control the order of the variables, then you _really_ need to refactor your code from scratch.

Comment: Yes sir, that is the plan

Comment: @Oke Tega Thank you mate for the help. I see now that I should have comment the answers instead, apologize for this

Comment: Try refactoring your code from scartch if you can't control the order of your variables.Your code as is would cost a lot later in future if not fixed now.